# Is there a better way to add page backgrounds?

Tags: image

OOTB Sharepoint's look and feel functionality has an option where you're able to drop in your own backgrounds to display on your site.

The issue I'm having is that I'm using a pretty high-res image, so the background takes a few seconds to load and it's quite annoying watching it flash behind the interface every time myself or a user navigates to a different page.

Is there some way I can hard-code it into the masterpage so that it's loaded from the get-go, rather than being added in this sort of, "post-interface" state?

Answer (score 0):

In Sp2013 and SPO at least: Activate publishing feature and set custom CSS (no need to touch the master page) and and use ordinary CSS background image technique. Would be my choice.

Can't tell if it improves the experience though.